# write sorted results to file

Tags: python

I have a simple function that sorts a dictionary:

```
data = inputfile.readlines()
lineData = sorted(data, key=len, reverse=True)[:3]
```

Printing the output:

```
print sorted(data, key=len, reverse=True)[:3]
```

generates the expected result, however writing to file:

```
outputfile.writelines sorted(data, key=len, reverse=True)[:3]
```

generates nothing. How can I write the output to the text file (outputfile)?
The complete code is as follows:

```
import sys, string
inputfilenames, outputfilename = sys.argv[1:-1], sys.argv[-1]


def do_something_with_input(inputfile):
    data = inputfile.readlines()
    print sorted(data, key=len, reverse=True)[:3]
    print sys.path[0]+"/"+ outputfilename


def write_results(outputfile):
    data = inputfile.readlines()
    outputfile.writelines(sorted(data, key=len, reverse=True)[:3])

for inputfilename in inputfilenames:
    inputfile = open(inputfilename, "r")
    do_something_with_input(inputfile)
    outputfile = open(outputfilename, "w")
    write_results(outputfile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writelines` is a method, you need to call it:

```
outputfile.writelines(sorted(data, key=len, reverse=True)[:3])
```

**ETA**
Function `open` provides file handle which could be iterated over **once**. You do it in your `do_something_with_input` function, after the `inputfile` iterated over, iterator is exhausted. Which means any further iterations, such as done in your `write_results` functions would yield an empty sequence. That's why nothing is written to the output file. Basically, it is equivalent to:

```
>>> a = (i for i in range(2))
>>> list(a)
[0, 1]
>>> list(a)
[]
```

What you need to do is store the output of the `sorted(...)` and then write it to the file, not try to generate it again.

Comment: Thank you. Modifying the write_results function was exactly what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You write:

```
outputfile.writelines sorted(data, key=len, reverse=True)[:3]
```

> generates nothing.

it should actually generate a syntax-error exception because of the missing parentheses -- if it doesn't, I guess you must be using some (allegedly) "smart" IDE like iPython which puts in the parentheses on your behalf -- is that the case?

You're printing the three shortest lines, and they well may all be empty -- that should put three empty lines in your output file (and of course show nothing to stdout -- is that what you mean by "generates nothing"?).  Maybe you're not properly calling `outputfile.close()` so by the time you check the file they're still buffered and not written to disk yet.

As you see there are a huge number of possibilities around your very ambiguous "generates nothing" assertion.  Can you clarify **exactly** what environment you're using and how in particular you're checking what your code "generates" or doesn't?  Otherwise, it's very hard to help you much.

**Edit**: the OP clarified and showed his code -- and the problem is now clear: he's totally consuming `inputfile` the first time, never "rewinding" it, so the file immediately ends (no lines left in it) at the second `readlines` call.  If you do need to read the file twice independently (rather than just reading it once and passing the data around, as would be normal), you'll need a call `inputfile.seek(0)` to "rewind the file" each time you read it to make it ready to be read all over again.

Comment: Sorry. What I should have said was generates an empty text file. The entry has been edited to provide the complete code. I'm using IDLE.

Comment: Also, it should be calling the three longest lines. The printed output does so.

Comment: @kjarsenal, now that you show your code the problem has become clear, see my answer's edit.

Comment: Thank you Alex. Your instruction is greatly appreciated.